# Is there a physical description of the Keepers in Gloomwrought?

Tags: dnd-4e

I was reading through The Shadowfell: Gloomwrought and Beyond and the book speaks largely of a race called Keepers who are essentially caretakers of the city that have been around as long as the city has.  I have not read a physical description of them, though.  Is that up for a DM to homebrew, or is there a description in another book (or did i just accidentally read over it in the book)?

Comment: Are you looking for exclusively *D&D 4e* information how keepers appear? (They actually date back to *AD&D* 2e.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a description of the Keepers in *The Shadowfell: Gloomwrought and Beyond.* It's not much of one but can be found on page 106:

> Keepers can shift between humanoid form and a motile mass of viscous black tar...

The *Manual of the Planes,* however, goes in to slightly more detail (though it's still not much), as found on page 59:

> The Keepers are a race of creatures that seem human at first glance, but are less mortal than they appear. Keepers have pale, hairless skin and cover their bodies in heavy, black leather smocks, sometimes studded with silver skulls. Black goggles fit snugly over their eyes, hiding their intentions behind panes of black glass [...] They don't like conflict; when confronted, they collapse into a puddle of gooey tar and slither toward the nearest canal.

This would seem to suggest that the accompanying picture on page 106 in *The Shadowfell: Gloomwrought and Beyond* is a depiction of a Keeper. They look quite nosferatuesque in my opinion.